# Where is this module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html used?

Tags: html, magento, requirejs, magento2

I am basically going through the [RequireJS section of the official Magento 2](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/requirejs/) documentation and there is a section which mentions about changing the maxlength of an input tag with `class="admin__control-text"` to 512, which is supposed to be 256 by default.

I am facing difficulty locating where this is being used in Magento 2. Even with the template hints turned on, I am not able to find which form input in the adminhtml or frontend areas is this file is getting applied. I tried checking the adminhtml area and could see the class "admin__control-text" in some places however they came from some other template and not this one which is inside `vendor/magento/module_ui`.

So even after creating the file I am not able to check and confirm if the additions that I made in my `app/code/<Vendor_name>/<module_name>/view/base/web/template/form/element` to the maxlength are being applied as I don't know where to check and if this file is getting applied.

Can someone please help with this? I have been stuck on this for quite some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the other files needed to you module in order to work and add correctly to Magento2, like `requirejs-config.js`, `registration.php` and `module.xml`?

```js
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'ui/template/form/element/input': '<Vendor_name>_<module_name>/template/form/element/input'
        }
    }
};
```

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '<Vendor_name>_<module_name>',
    __DIR__
);
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="<Vendor_name>_<module_name>" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Ui" />
            <module name="Magento_Backend" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The issue was resolved later. As it turns out it I had kept it in view/adminHtml/web/ instead of view/base/web/

Comment: Your welcome! Glad to hear you already solved it!